# There are BI / OLAP tools for MEAN Stack platform?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, business-intelligence, olap, mean-stack

Can anyone indicate me to a framework of *BI / OLAP* or at least a *Chart Engine*, preferably open source, which properly integrate with [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/) or [MEAN.IO](http://mean.io/) platform in *SPA - Single Page Application* architecture?

I know the **keen.io**. It is free in low transactional volume, but it is not open-source.

The [Pentaho](http://community.pentaho.com/) is a great BI tool, it's open-source, has *RESTful Services* and supports *MongoDB*, but your dashboard still employs Java on the server side and is one generation behind frameworks like *Node.js* and *Angular.JS* and they are only migrating now for *jQuery* and *Bootstrap*.

Thank you in advance for any contribution.

Comment: Pentaho uses jQuery on its Dashboard framework (CDF) for a few years now. It's true that only now explicit support for bootstrap was added, but it's an open-ended framework and you are free to include any other library you want. If you want to use Raphael, D3 or any other you can easily include them in your dashboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Discovery 1

There is a amazing API, similar to *jQuery* in objective of manipulate *DOM* for you to compose graphic charts, named **D3.JS - Data-Driven Documents** [d3js.org](http://d3js.org/).

### Discovery 2

There is a chart engine named **NVD3** [nvd3.org](http://nvd3.org), built on *D3.JS*, that allow you apply re-usable chart components in your *Javascript* applications.

### Discovery 3

There is a *Angular.JS* module named **AngularJS-NVD3-directives** http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/, that integrate the chart components of *NVD3* into directives of *Angular.JS*, allowing use it natively in your *Angular.JS* applications.

### The Open Source Solution for MEAN Stack

You can integrate *AngularJS-NVD3-directives* components with Pentaho RESTful services via *Mongoose* accessing your *MongoDB* data to build dashboards and scoreboards control panels for your applications.

You still need to write code to integrate each of the components of a control panel as grid layout, themes, field projection and visibility, filter, sort, pivot tables and charts.

Today, the development process of control panels isn't straightforward, but you already have an open source solution good enough to design impressive applications.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used them and may be they're not what you're looking for, but you should definitively take a look to this two projects: [d3js](http://d3js.org/) and [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Hope this helps you!